# Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed - inside VerticalPdfViewPager

Tags: android, kotlin

When I click outside the PDF viewer, I get a blank screen as in the second picture.

## (https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7fAV.jpg) (https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yjlR.jpg)

It is necessary to disable the click outside the pdf viewer or when the user clicks outside to return him to the previous screen. Thank you

class PdfViewerActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var pdfViewPager: VerticalPdfViewPager
private lateinit var img_back: ImageView

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
window.decorView.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.dashboardGraphDescription,theme))
        val dialogView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_pdf_viewer, null)
        pdfViewPager = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.pdfViewPager)
        img_back = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.image_back_pdf_viewer)

        val pdfFileName = "TermsAndConditions2023.pdf"
        val pdfFile = getFileFromAssets(this, pdfFileName)

        if (pdfFile.exists()) {
            pdfViewPager.adapter = PDFPagerAdapter(this, pdfFile.absolutePath)
        } else {
            // Handle the error
        }

        val alertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setView(dialogView)
            .setCancelable(true)
            .create()

        alertDialog.show()

        // Set the dialog size
        val dialogWidth = (resources.displayMetrics.widthPixels * 0.9).toInt()
        val dialogHeight = (resources.displayMetrics.heightPixels * 0.6).toInt()
        alertDialog.window?.setLayout(dialogWidth, dialogHeight)

        img_back.setOnClickListener {
            onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()
            finish()
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        (pdfViewPager.adapter as? PDFPagerAdapter)?.close()
    }

    @Deprecated("Deprecated in Java")
    override fun onBackPressed() {
        super.getOnBackPressedDispatcher().onBackPressed()
    }
companion object {
        fun getFileFromAssets(context: Context, assetName: String): File {
            val file = File(context.cacheDir, assetName)

            if (!file.exists()) {
                try {
                    file.createNewFile()
                    val inputStream = context.assets.open(assetName)
                    val outputStream = FileOutputStream(file)
                    inputStream.copyTo(outputStream)
                    outputStream.flush()
                    inputStream.close()
                    outputStream.close()
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }

            return file
        }
    }
}
```